# Extract Active Directory into SQL database using VBScript

Tags: t-sql, vbscript, ssis

I have written a VBScript to extract data from Active Directory into a record set. I'm now wondering what the most efficient way is to transfer the data into a SQL database.

I'm torn between;

- Writing it to an excel file then firing an SSIS package to import it or...
- Within the VBScript, iterating through the dataset in memory and submitting 3000+ `INSERT` commands to the SQL database

Would the latter option result in 3000+ round trips communicating with the database and therefore be the slower of the two options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending an insert row by row is always the slowest option.  This is what is known as Row by Agonizing Row or RBAR.  You should avoid that if possible and take advantage of set based operations.

Your other option, writing to an intermediate file is a good option, I agree with @Remou in the comments that you should probably pick CSV rather than Excel if you are going to choose this option.

I would propose a third option.  You already have the design in VB contained in your VBscript.  You should be able to convert this easily to a script component in SSIS.  Create an SSIS package, add a DataFlow task, add a Script Component ([as a datasource {example here}](http://bobp1339.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-use-ssis-script-component-as.html)) to the flow, write your fields out to the output buffer, and then add a sql destination and save yourself the step of writing to an intermediate file.  This is also more secure, as you don't have your AD data on disk in plaintext anywhere during the process.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how often this will run or if you have to run it within a certain time window, so it isn't clear that performance is even an issue here. "Slow" doesn't mean anything by itself: a process that runs for 30 minutes can be perfectly acceptable if the time window is one hour.

Just write the simplest, most maintainable code you can to get the job done and go from there. If it runs in an acceptable amount of time then you're done. If it doesn't, then at least you have a clean, functioning solution that you can profile and optimize.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have it in a dataset and if it's SQL Server 2008+ create a [user defined table type](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html) and send the whole dataset in as an atomic unit.

And if you go the SSIS route, I have a post covering [Active Directory as an SSIS Data Source](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html)